# Human-Computer Interaction PhD in Computer Science vs Information Systems: Does the department title matter?

Tags: phd, computer-science, career-path

I've been offered a PhD position in Human-Computer Interaction, but it bothers me that it's within the Business/Economics department, so it would yield me an Information Systems degree instead of a Computer Science degree. I'm afraid that this would close some doors of HCI jobs that list CS degrees as requirements. I will be doing CS work, and I believe it would be important to get such recognition.

Do you guys the title of my PhD in this case is something important, or I shouldn't be worried about it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would depend on the university. HCI is highly regarded and essential in many aspects of computing, but it is a bit at the cusp of CS and more general (human centered) things. It can be rich in psychology, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to high-tech industry job (vs academic jobs) I can only tell you that for me, if I'm looking for R&D, design, development roles I would hire someone with a CS degree over IS degree without even looking into qualifications. It is unlikely I will look at you resume farther than the part that mentions your degree.  Unless of course I am unable to find people and am rather desperate.

Think about it this way:  this is degree from Business/Economics department which translates into a non (engineering/technology) degree which is not what a job with CS requirement would be looking for.

But again, it depends on kind of a job you are thinking about and can't claim  that this is the view of everyone although I can comfortably say it would cut your chances a good deal for the kind of jobs I mentioned above.

Sorry if I sound harsh.

Comment: Thanks for your honest feedback! That's exactly what I had in mind, and that's why my supervisor and I will be working towards getting cotutelle from another university so that I can get a double degree as CS and IS. Do you believe that would solve the issue?

Comment: I think it would. In the least it will get your Resume past the initial screening (which in most cases is done by some admin or an intern or even an automated filter  who is just checking the boxes) and to hiring managers/people who would look at the details.